# Optical viewfinder sun shade?

Tags: viewfinder, accessories

When taking photographs on a sunny day, I typically find myself holding the actual camera with my right hand, while using my left hand to cup the space between my face and the camera's optical viewfinder so I can see some actual contrast without being dazzled by the Sun.

This is fine with small, light-weight lenses. It works poorly with really heavy ones.

How do other people deal with this? Is there some kind of product you can buy that shades the viewfinder for you? Or is this just a case of more expensive DSLR bodies having a better viewfinder design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aftermarket eye cups are available for many camera models that replace the supplied eyecup with a larger cup that fits the face of the user.

[image: Altura Rubber Eyecup]

[Here is one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0020HRCB6) made for the Canon 5d and 5D Mark II as well as other Canon cameras that have an 18mm eyepiece slot.

[image: Hoodman H-EYEC18L HoodEYE for 5D and 5D Mark II DSLR Cameras]

There are also [versions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0078YX3M8) made a bit larger for people who wear eyeglasses.

[image: Altura Rubber Eyecup for Eyeglasses]

[image: Hoodman Glasses Model Hoodeye Eyecup for Canon 5D Mark III, 7D, 1D, and 1DS Mark III Models]

[Similar items](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008MLAT78) are also available for many Nikon camera models.

[Right angle viewfinders](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=canon%20right%20angle%20viewfinder) are also available for a variety of camera models and usually include a rubber eyecup that helps block off axis light from the user's eye.

[image: Canon Angle Finder C]

Since such accessories are model specific and you haven't included the particular camera in question, we can't provide an exact match for whatever particular camera you are using.

Comment: Interesting. This seems relevant. What search term would I use to find these kinds of items? "Eye cup" or something? (Personally, I shoot the Nikon D3300, but the next person to read this answer might use something else...)

Comment: SInce the products in most of the links above are described as *Rubber Eyecup* or *Right Angle Viewfinder*...

Comment: Hoodman has been making such rubber eyecups for a long time, and some people call them a "Hoodman", even if made by another company.

Comment: And for what it is worth, the *similar items* link in the answer will fit your D3300, as will any eyecup replacement made for Nikon square 22mm viewfinders.

Comment: I see some useful looking hits from Amazon UK. Pretty cheap too. Clearly I'll have to try this out... Thanks!

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Nikon makes rubber eyecups for most of their cameras. One of the most used ones is Nikon DK-19, it screws onto the round viewfinder on some camera models. There is also a small adapter you can buy if you need to mount DK-19 on camera with a rectangular viewfinder. There are plenty of both on ebay, either original ones, or knockoffs.

Comment: @lightproof The DK-19 is good for a cushion, but doesn't block out much stray light.

Comment: @MichaelClark in fact, it does. At least if you don't wear glasses. It cups the eye completely from all sides, so you don't see anything except viewfinder. I have been using it for the last couple of years and it works so good it's a pain to use any camera without it now :)

Comment: It doesn't look to have a "wing" that follows the contour of the face and wraps around the outside edge of the eye. It may well shade more than it looks, but I doubt it does as much as a hoodman type cup that is shaped like the eyepieces in the classic very high end cinema cameras. http://www.cinemagear.com/images/accessories/Doors%20and%20Eyepieces/Angenieux%20viewfinder%204-11350-large.jpg